# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 112211

Tags: java

More details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Person.blirVennMed(Oblig1.java:68)
    at Vet.vennskap(Oblig1.java:151)
    at Oblig1.main(Oblig1.java:117)
```

Here is the problem:

```
    import java.util.*;

class Person {
    private String navn;
    private Person[] kjenner;
    private Person[] likerikke; 
    private Person forelsketi;
    private Person sammenmed;
    private int antallvenner = 0;
    private int antallvenner1 = 0; 
    private int teller = 0;
    private Person[] venner;
    private Person[] ikkevenner;

    Person(String n, int lengde) {
        navn = n;
        kjenner = new Person[lengde];
        likerikke = new Person[kjenner.length];
        venner = new Person[kjenner.length];
        ikkevenner = new Person[kjenner.length];
    }

    public void blirVennMed(Person p) {
        for (int i = 0; i<ikkevenner.length; i++) {
            if (likerikke == null && navn != p.hentNavn()) {
                venner[teller++] = p;
            }
            if (likerikke != null && navn != p.hentNavn()) {
                if (p.hentNavn().equals(ikkevenner[i].hentNavn())) { 
                    venner[teller++] = p;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java =/= JavaScript. Tag removed. Also, what's with the random text at the bottom of your question?

Comment: When I was uploading it said it needed more description, so I had to take it in!

Comment: Still, don't add a language that is not relevant to your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have just declare your `ikkevenner` array of type `Person`. but, you didn't initialize the values in your array. You need to initialize each index of the `ikkevenner` array with `Person` instance like

```
//initializing the values in array
ikkevenner[i] = new Person(name,id);
```

In your code:

```
//ikkevenner[i] is null, it will throw NPE
ikkevenner[i].hentNavn()
```

When you declare the `ikkevenner` array of type `Person`, all the index values in the array will be null. When you invoke a method on null, it will throw NullPointerException. If you have initialized the array variables somewhere, the other probablities which can cause NPE are

```
1) When Person p (argument) passed to the method is null
2) p.hentNavn() is null
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't I do that by: ikkevenner = new Person[kjenner.length];

Comment: This will just create the array of type Person. You need to fill it with Person instances

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it worked for you. I am telling this since you are new to SO. so, that any body who come across this question knows which one worked for you